# Failed to install R in Ubuntu

Tags: r

```
R --version
/usr/local/bin/R: line 248: /usr/local/lib/R/etc/ldpaths: No such file or directory
/usr/local/bin/R: line 271: /usr/local/lib/R/bin/exec/R: No such file or directory
```

Before it, I have installed R in my laptop, but I wanna upgrade my R version (because version 3.4 not support any library), so I deleted R directory with `rmdir /usr/local/lib/R` or I don't know, btw I have tried every method, I am a new Ubuntu 18 user so I try everything what I face on StackOverflow etc.

I just wanna install R with 3.6 version, I think it has installed. Because R app has exist. But when I access `R --version`, the output is like that.

Comment: You installed a new version of R, correct? Have you added that to your path?

Comment: How I know? I just try and try, I am a new user, so I just try and dont understand what i have writen :')

Comment: From searching a bit around I found [this](https://community.rstudio.com/t/r-line-238-usr-local-lib-r-etc-ldpaths-no-such-file-or-directory/19006/10) thread describing your issue might be related to failed removal of the old R installation. See if it helps you along :)

Comment: you installed it with: ```sudo apt install r-base-core```?